# Clientside workarounds for window.onload never being triggered due to external stylesheet @font-face Cross origin load fail in firefox

Tags: javascript, css, cross-domain, font-face, onload

So its news to me, but apparently in firefox, the window.onload event can be blocked indefinitely by loading an external stylesheet that contains an @font-face rule with a font also hosted on the external site that doesn't allow serving the font to anyone(likely because of the mime type not being configured for Access-Control-Origin : * etc).

Now my question isn't how to configure a server to fix this or rewrite the css, but a bit more esoteric.
In the event that window.onload is never triggered due to this scenario, what can we do from the client
side, via javascript, to still allow necessary code in onLoad handlers to fire?

All I can think of is to arbitrarily use a setTimeout as a fallback, which seems unreliable as you can imagine based on this question the scope of size and resources of pages being loaded will vary greatly.

It does seem at least the aspect of the onload not firing must be some kind of bug.  Seems like after the browser realizes it can't load the font it should give up on it and let the window load continue...

**DEMO**

Using this simple code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", myScript);

function myScript(){
 alert('test');   
}
```

Check out this jsfiddle with an external stylesheet commented out.  Then uncomment it and hit run again.  The behavior I'm describing even stops the regular jsfiddle onload stuff from firing.

[JSFIDDLE DEMO LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/52kbfkgb/3/)

Cheers!

Comment: Bet that was fun to figure out!

Comment: oh god.  you have no idea.... :P